# TeXStudio does not load dictionary files

Tags: mac, texstudio

I have the following problem with TeXStudio. I have several dictionaries installed in the correct directory but the program does not recognize them. Actually the list of dictionaries that appears under the default tab in the general preferences is always empty. I tried to change the directory with no success. I am running TeXStudio with Mac OS X.
Any suggestion?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 3):

What is your definition of “correct directory”? May dictionary are placed in `/Applications/texstudio.app/Contents/Resources`.

[image: TeXstudio preferences]

You can access this directory by ctrl-clicking o TeXstudio and then “show package contents”

To set this folder in TeXstudio open it in Finder and drag it to the window where you can select the dictionary directory

[image]

Comment: This is what I did but for some reason dictionaries did not appear on the list. Anyhow I solved the problem reinstalling the program now it works

Comment: I had the same problem, i.e. the right path appeared in the field '_spelling dictionary directory_' but no dictionary appeared in the field '_Default language_'.
I just refreshed the spelling dictionary directory by changing it and doing the procedure described above, and it worked out.